# Consistently high disk usage hinders performance

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-8.1, performance

I have a Asus quad-core Laptop running windows8.1, and it has high disk usage, for the entire time it is running. Its not like its doing anything, (that I know about) Just 100% disk usage, all the time. I was looking into performance issues, when I noticed the disk usage was way up, and never seems to come down.

I tried disabling all the services I don't need, but disk usage remains high, and performance remains poor. What can I do?

Comment: does your HDD report itself as being healthy?

Comment: yes using speed-fan SMART DISK UTILITY

Comment: install the WPT (part of the Win8.1 SDK: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891), run WPRUI.exe, select **CPU, Disk, FileIO**, run it for 1 minute and store the data into an ETL file.Compress this ETL as 7z/RAR, upload it to Onedrive, create a share link and post the link here.

Comment: have you captured the disk usage trace?